# how can i read from the documents directory in the iphone at run time?

Tags: iphone

I'm implemanting in an iphone app a .plist file that contain some initial parameters that i'll use later in the app, i create a NSMutableArray myArray with a NSMutableDictionary with some keys then i create the file:

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"Initial.plist"];
[myArray writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

i acccess the content of this file as:

```
NSMutableArray *temp= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

everthing works fine in the simulator but when i run a test in a device the content of temp always is null, i don't have any idea why i get a nil Array maybe i'm doing somthing wrong accessing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the value of `filePath` on the simulator, and on the device?

Use of `stringByAppendingString` seems odd to me in this case -- shouldn't that be `stringByAppendingPathExtension` instead? I would guess that it's missing a "/" in the path because of that, but you say it works on the simulator...

Comment: Probably one should use stringByAppendingPathComponent