# Store a BOOL on app close

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, persistence, boolean

In my project I would like to store a `BOOL` value when I close the app, so that when I open the app again, the value is the same. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this in your application delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"myKey"];
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    BOOL myKey = [defaults boolForKey:@"myKey"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSUserDefaults for this. You can found how to use NSUserDefaults here-

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Answer (score 2):

Use NSUserDefaults to write to a file on in the documents directory. Store the BOOL in an NSNumber container (*[NSNumber numberWithBool:boolValue]*). To retrieve the value on startup, get the value from the NSNumber container object (*[someNumberObject boolValue]*). Pretty basic stuff to be honest.

**Edit:** check this post for an example: [how can i read from the documents directory in the iphone at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890406/how-can-i-read-from-the-documents-directory-in-the-iphone-at-run-time)

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` has methods to store and retrieve bools directly - `-setBool:ForKey:` and `-boolForKey:`